# ExtJS - Ordenar columna (renderizada) por raw data

Tags: javascript, extjs

Tengo una grid con una columna ('**prioridad**') a la cual se le aplica un renderer para mostrar un texto según el valor que tenga. Al tratarse de una columna de prioridades estaremos trabajando con los siguientes valores:

```
1 = 'baja'
2 = 'media'
3 = 'alta'
4 = 'critica'
```

Lo que quiero es que me ordene por los valores numéricos originales y no por los renderizados, ya que en este caso no tiene sentido la ordenación alfabética.

> Este es el código de la **grid**:

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    itemId: 'MOTIVOS',
    store: modulo.motivos,
    columns: [
            { text: 'id', width: 68, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id', align:'right' },
            { text: 'motivo', width: 540, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'descripcion' },
            { text: 'ambito', width: 110, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'ambito' },
            { text: 'area', width: 160, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'area', readonly: true },

            {
                text: 'prioridad', width: 100, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'prioridad',
                renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                    return me.modulo.getUtils().renderPrioridad(value);     //the render function
                },
                readonly: true
            },
            { text: 'numProtocolos', width: 102, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'numProto', align: 'center' }
        ]
};
```

> El modelo del **store**:

```
Ext.define('app.model.Motivo', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [
       { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
       { name: 'ambito', type: 'string' },
       { name: 'area', type: 'string' },
       { name: 'subarea', type: 'string' },
       { name: 'descripcion', type: 'string' },
       { name: 'prioridad', type: 'int' },
       { name: 'numProto', type:'int'}
   ]
 });
```

La columna **'prioridad'** es del tipo `int` pero es renderizada con los strings acorde a su prioridad (*Alta* (3) / *Media* (2) / *Baja* (1)).

En la grid se me ordenan por estos strings en vez de los valores numéricos *reales* que hay detrás (3,2,1) y necesito que me ordene por estos valores manteniendo visibles las palabras renderizadas para la UX.

Comment: Se me ocurre una cosa... Has probado en crear en el modelo una especie de alias o maping de prioridad? Al estilo PrioridadLabel = prioridad.

Comment: (envié el anterior sin terminar sin querer) luego en el columns del grid utilizas prioridadLabel para aplicarle ese renderer y mantén el dataIndex en "prioridad".

Comment: Parece ser una buena idea y merece la pena testearlo. Gracias, lo probaré a ver si eso funciona

Comment: @Soteck podrías ilustrar lo del maping con 1 ejemplo?